# Highcharts Using CSV instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I tried the code like this with many small restructuration and modification but without success.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length,
            // set the allowed units for data grouping
            groupingUnits = [[
                'week',                         // unit name
                [1]                             // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]],

            i = 0;

        for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }

        $('#chart').highcharts({

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Historical'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],
            data: {
                csv: data
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Here is data.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2013-12-20,9371.08,9413.09,9352.98,9400.18,161686900
2013-12-19,9279.68,9351.9,9257.24,9335.74,98276500
2013-12-18,9145.35,9190.73,9122.05,9181.75,82342700
2013-12-17,9142.75,9161.8,9085.12,9085.12,72207500
2013-12-16,9004.62,9187.78,8997.75,9163.56,99105600
2013-12-13,9016.78,9046.63,8990.58,9006.46,67761700
2013-12-12,9032.67,9060.54,8984.28,9017,75120200
2013-12-11,9093.26,9153.14,9065.51,9077.11,64845800
2013-12-10,9180.29,9223.73,9091.97,9114.44,74363400
```

Can you help me to figure out the problem or purpose new approch please ?

**What is my goal ?**

Is to be able to load a CSV file inside the chart instead of using JSON file.

**Why ?**

Because modifing CSV file is more easier for me using PHP than JSON, and it's for performance too.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `data.length`, you are getting length of the csv file string. What you need to do is split the data with the newline delimiter.

```
// sample from data

var data = `Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2013-12-20,9371.08,9413.09,9352.98,9400.18,161686900
2013-12-19,9279.68,9351.9,9257.24,9335.74,98276500`;


// split by \n (new line)

data = data.split('\n'); // now data is an array of rows

var finalObj = [];

// iterate over the rows
data.map(function(row){
    var obj = {};

    // row is a string separated by ','

    row = row.split(','); // now row is an array 

    obj['date'] = row[0];
    obj['open'] = row[1];
    obj['high'] = row[2];
    obj['low'] = row[3];
    obj['close'] = row[4];
    obj['volume'] = row[5];

    finalObj.push(obj);
})


console.log(finalObj);
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      date:'Date',
      open:'Open',
      high:'High',
      low:'Low',
      close:'Close',
      volume:'Volume'
   },
   {
      date:'2013-12-20',
      open:'9371.08',
      high:'9413.09',
      low:'9352.98',
      close:'9400.18',
      volume:'161686900'
   },
   {
      date:'2013-12-19',
      open:'9279.68',
      high:'9351.9',
      low:'9257.24',
      close:'9335.74',
      volume:'98276500'
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After many searches i succeeded to make it working by spliting the lines and then `$.each(data, function(lineNo, line)` to get each line and then extract each value spliting the line again like you did.